# Change update action in jeditable rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, action, jeditable

I would like that the editable_field call a custom action in my controller instead to call the 'update' method.

This is my code in the haml file (i write the action i want to invoke in the :action attribute):

```
editable_field(today_clockings[col-1], :clocking, |
   {:update_url => resource_clocking_path(@resource, today_clockings[col-1]), :action => "update_ts_clocking"}) |
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you would have to edit your routes file to create a route to the action.  For example:

In **routes.rb**

```
match "today_clocking/update_ts_clocking" => 'today_clocking#update_ts_clocking', :as => :update_ts_clocking
```

Then in your **view**:

```
<%= editable_field(today_clockings[col-1], :clocking, {:update_url => update_ts_clocking_path) %>
```

Then the **today_clockings_controller.rb** would be something like:

```
def update_ts_clocking
    # Update model here with params[:today_clocking][:clocking]
end
```